# Struggling in Unity 3d object Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm totally new to Unity and game development...I made a 2D object of the car that can move to 8 directions....each direction with the specific animation of the car's movement...Now, how do I make my car move in such a way that if it's moving straight LEFT it shouldn't go immediately straight to RIGHT when turning RIGHT, so I want it to make a proper round turn or a "U TURN" to move towards its opposite direction and obviously the same with UP and DOWN turns....can anyone please help me in at least one way I can fix this?

or the other way to ask this question would be if I'm moving my object to x = -1 direction then on turning to x = 1 it should first go through x = 0 and then x = 1 so that it looks like a turn.

this is the code for my CAR so far..

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CARmovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private Vector3 change;
    private Animator animator;
    private Vector3 lastMoveDirection;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        change = Vector3.zero;
        change.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        change.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        UpdateAnimationAndMove();

    }

    void UpdateAnimationAndMove()
    {
        if (change != Vector3.zero)
        {
            MoveCar();
            animator.SetFloat("moveX", change.x);

            animator.SetFloat("moveY", change.y);
            animator.SetBool("driving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("driving", false);
        }
    }
    void MoveCar()
    {
        myRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + change * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: transform.Rotate(x, y, z): Take the own coordinate system as a reference, rotate around the X axis, Y axis, and Z axis at a constant speed with x degrees, y degrees, and z degrees, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I try an example of rotating a car. We add an object (here I add a car as an example), select the object (car) to create a C# Script script, double-click to open, we define two variables Speed_move, Speed_rot to control the movement speed and Rotation speed and assign values to them. We use Translate to control the forward and backward movement of the cube through the W and S buttons, forward with forward, and back with back; use Rotate to control the rotation of the object through the A and D buttons, up is the Y-axis rotation. The following is the code for the specific rotation.

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))

{

```
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed_move);
```

}

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))

    {

        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * Speed_move);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))

    {

        this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * -Speed_rot);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))

    {

        this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * Speed_rot);

    }
```